# AWS & NodeJs http request to external api

Tags: node.js, rest, aws-lambda

Just trying NodeJs and AWS Lambda. So far I managed to use Serverless to build all my stack and create my Gateway and Lambdas. Now I am struggling with something that should be so simple, calling an external API.

I have tried a couple of codes and some other I have found here on Stackoverflow, but so far I failed, all of them return to the browser a message with Internal Server Error. These are codes I thought I had the closest result:

Code Sample 1:

```
import { Handler, Context, Callback } from 'aws-lambda';
import http from 'https';
    const regioes: Handler = (event: any, context: Context, callback: Callback) => {
      var url: string = 'https://servicodados.ibge.gov.br/api/v1/localidades/regioes';
      https.get(url, function(res) {
        var data = '';
        res.on('data', (chunk) => { data += chunk; }); 
        res.on('end', () => { console.log("BODY: " + data); });
        }).on('error', (e) => { console.log("Got error: " + e.message);});

    };
    export {regioes}
```

Code Sample 2:

```
import { Handler, Context, Callback } from 'aws-lambda';
import http from 'https';
const regioes: Handler = (event: any, context: Context, callback: Callback) => {
  var url: string = 'https://servicodados.ibge.gov.br/api/v1/localidades/regioes';
  let body: any;
  let response: httpResponse = {
    statusCode: 200,
    body: JSON.stringify({
      message:'Variavel response inicializada', test: 'i am a text'
      }),
    isBase64Encoded: false
  };
  console.log('resposta padrao', response);
  var reqOptions: https.RequestOptions = {
    host: 'servicodados.ibge.gov.br',
    path: '/api/v1/localidades/regioes',
    method: 'GET'
  }
  var req = https.request(reqOptions, res => {
    console.log("statusCode: ", res.statusCode);
    res.on('data', function (chunk) {
      body += chunk;
  });
    res.on('end', () => {
       response = {
          statusCode: 200,
          body: JSON.stringify({message: 'test'}),
          isBase64Encoded: false
      };

    });
  }).on('error', (err) => {
    console.log(err);
    response = {
      statusCode: 500,
      body: JSON.stringify ({ message: err.message}),
      isBase64Encoded: false
    }

  });
  req.end();
  callback(null, response);
};

export {regioes}
```

Code 3 - The one from AWS blueprint template:

```
const https = require('https');

/**
 * Pass the data to send as `event.data`, and the request options as
 * `event.options`. For more information see the HTTPS module documentation
 * at https://nodejs.org/api/https.html.
 *
 * Will succeed with the response body.
 */
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    const req = https.request(event.options, (res) => {
        let body = '';
        console.log('Status:', res.statusCode);
        console.log('Headers:', JSON.stringify(res.headers));
        res.setEncoding('utf8');
        res.on('data', (chunk) => body += chunk);
        res.on('end', () => {
            console.log('Successfully processed HTTPS response');
            // If we know it's JSON, parse it
            if (res.headers['content-type'] === 'application/json') {
                body = JSON.parse(body);
            }
            callback(null, body);
        });
    });
    req.on('error', callback);
    //req.write(JSON.stringify(event.data));
    req.end();
};
```

I know code sample 1 is missing the return of the body, didn't add it there as I was trying to check if the return was any different on CloudWatch, it is the same for both, no errors, but none of the console log messages I added.

Code sample 3 is the template from AWS. I just set a Test and pass the options of https for the connection. What I find interesting is:

```
{
  "options": {
      "protocol": "https:",
      "hostname": "servicodados.ibge.gov.br",
      "path": "/api/v1/localidades/regioes",
      "method": "GET"
  }
}
```

The above code times out just like any other code.

```
{
  "options": {
      "protocol": "https:",
      "hostname": "servicodados.ibge.gov.br/api/v1/localidades",
      "path": "/regioes",
      "method": "GET"
  }
}
```

The above fails as expected, since the hostname is incorrect and the error message is:

```
Response:
{
  "errorMessage": "getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND servicodados.ibge.gov.br/api/v1/localidades servicodados.ibge.gov.br/api/v1/localidades:443",
  "errorType": "Error",
  "stackTrace": [
    "errnoException (dns.js:50:10)",
    "GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:92:26)"
  ]
}
```

So, I presume the call being triggered, because the above code identified the host is incorrect, but still it times out. Please note that all codes fail tests running inside AWS Lambda, and consequently they do fail the same way and for the same reason when triggered from API Gateway.

If you call the endpoint on my code, you will notice it will return a simple JSON, no authentication required, it is a public API and I make use of it on a Java project.

Can someone point to me where is my error?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are using a proxy integration. You will need to stringify the `body` property of the response object. [See the docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-integration-settings-integration-response.html)

> With the Lambda proxy integration, the Lambda function must return
>   output of the following format:

```
{
    statusCode: "...",            // a valid HTTP status code
    headers: { 
        custom-header: "..."      // any API-specific custom header
    },
    body: "...",                  // a JSON string.
    isBase64Encoded:  true|false  // for binary support
}
```

Comment: Isn't what is being done on Code Sample 2, on the `res.on('end'`... line?

Comment: Also, even if we consider the reply format is incorrect, the messages within the console.log should be triggered and displayed on the CloudWatch logs, and they are they are not.

Comment: Does not look like it is being stringified at all in code sample 2. It is not the error in terms of Lambda function execution so it won't fall into `error` block. It is API Gateway error so won't show up in Lambda CloudWatch. You can try console.log response object before returning it to verify that it conforms to the required format.

Comment: I have done as per your suggestions. First I removed the code and tried to create the return output using the format you mentioned. I happens that it works as assumed (I use them for other lambdas). I have added the console.log with the return before the call of the http, and the output is presented on the CloudWatch log. But once I try to implement the login, it fails again, running a test on the API Gateway returns an error, I have added the error output to my question. As per message, it does seems my http request code is incorrect.